# Angular: MatFormFieldControl Error when using ngIf and iteration

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-forms

I'm trying to iterate through a JSON object and create mat-form-field inputs where the type varies based on a specific JSON value. I am iterating through my object like so

```
 <mat-form-field *ngFor="let entry of item.entry" class="form-field" appearance="outline">
  <input matInput id={{entry.id}} value={{entry.value}}>
 </mat-form-field>
```

This works no problem. However, when I go to check the format of the entry (which is included in the JSON object) like so...

```
<mat-form-field *ngFor="let entry of item.entry" class="form-field" appearance="outline">
  <input matInput *ngIf="entry.format=='STRING'" id={{entry.id}} value={{entry.value}}>
  <input matInput *ngIf="entry.format=='INTEGER'" id={{entry.id}} value={{entry.value}} type="number">
 </mat-form-field>
```

I receive the error: `ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.`

This doesn't make sense to me, seing as the matInput never changes. Am I missing something?

Here is a sample of the JSON structure I am referencing as well:

```
{ 
     "group-name":"Core",
     "entry":[ 
        { 
           "id":"foo",
           "value":"foo",
           "format":"STRING",
           "label":"IP Address",
           "edit":true,
           "tool-tip":"Insert Host IP Address",
           "hidden":false
        },
        { 
           "id":"bar",
           "value":"4200",
           "format":"INTEGER",
           "label":"Port",
           "edit":true,
           "tool-tip":"Port for connections",
           "hidden":false
        },
     ]
  },
```

Any Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The error speaks for itself:

> The `mat-form-field` must contain a MatFormFieldControl

In other words, it's saying that your `input` must be "*static*", you can't have a `*ngIf` encapsulating it.

---

What you can do to solve your case is something like this:

***TS (Component)***:

```
readonly inputTypeMapper = {
  INTEGER: 'number'
  STRING: 'text',
};
```

***HTML (Template)***:

```
<mat-form-field *ngFor="let entry of item.entry" class="form-field" appearance="outline">
  <input 
    matInput
    [id]="entry.id"
    [type]="inputTypeMapper[entry.format]"
    [value]="entry.value">
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your mistake is using the dot notation in your ngFor loop.

The correct use of the ngFor loop is:

```
*ngFor="let entry of entries"
```

So in your case, it would be:

```
*ngFor="let e of entries"
```

This is because you want to loop though the entries individually (as an entry, e in your case). Then when you have each entry in the loop - looking at one entry, you can then grab the information, with the dot notation.

You use the dot notation to access the items in the object, as you have done correctly for the interpolation: `{{ entry.id }}`

You can pass the ID back to the ts file, using property binding `[value]="entry.id"`

[Supporting Documentation from Angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data)
Best of luck! It just gets easier.